# Logout in action bar

Tags: java, android, logout

For my application I used a bouton to logout, but now I would like to use the action bar (When user click on logout icon he goes to homepage) and I can't make them live together.

(I'm french, its hard to code because all tuto are in english. So please be patient with me).

Thank you very much.

**My button code was :**

```
btn_logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sessionManager.logout();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

**My code where I would like to add icon logout :**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**My XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off"
        android:title="@string/logout"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Comment: put this code ( sessionManager.logout();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();) under here (if (id == R.id.action_logout) {)  then you can delete all the click  code (btn_logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { .........)

Comment: Thank you very much Tasos. It works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something when the user taps the menu item.

```
if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
    logout();
    return true;
}
```

Move your logout code to a method so you can call it from any place:

```
private void logout() {
    sessionManager.logout();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Work good like this. Thank you guys.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
            sessionManager.logout();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```